# Python generate text with format mydata_hh_mm

Tags: python

I have a number of csv files with name following the rule: mydata_hh_mm such as mydata_09_00.
hh is hour running from 06 to 09.
mm is minute running from 00 to 59.
I want to to generate the filename automatically so I can import them into a df?
The problem is the 0 when there is only 1 digit in hh or mm, which make this code below not working.

```
for i in range(7,10):  
    for j in range(0,60):
        file='mydata_' + '0' + str(i) + '_' + str(j) + '.csv' 
        alldata = pd.concat([alldata, pd.read_csv(rf'....csv')])
        print(file)
```

Comment: Try: `str(i).zfill(2)` for example. This will yield `'01'` if `i` is `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method to try which uses [f-strings](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#specification) and [formatting](https://peps.python.org/pep-0498/#format-specifiers).

```
for i in range(7,10):  
    for j in range(0,60):
        file = f'mydata_{i:02}_{j:02}.csv'
        print(file)
```

Essentially this works as: `{value:width}`. For example `{2:05}` will yield a string `'2'` padded to five characters: `'00002'`. Therefore your two character padding works as shown above.

Output:

```
mydata_07_00.csv
mydata_07_01.csv
...
mydata_09_58.csv
mydata_09_59.csv
```

---

**Note:** f-strings were introduced in Python 3.6.

Here is some [additional reading](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python) on the subject.